# Add method imports to shell_plus

Tags: django, django-extensions

In `shell_plus`, is there a way to automatically import selected helper methods, like the models are?

I often open the shell to type:

```
proj = Project.objects.get(project_id="asdf")
```

I want to replace that with:

```
proj = getproj("asdf")
```

Answer (score 21):

[Found it in the docs](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/docs/shell_plus.rst#additional-imports). Quoted from there:

> ### Additional Imports
>
> In addition to importing the models you can specify other items to
>   import by default. These are specified in `SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS` and
>   `SHELL_PLUS_POST_IMPORTS`. The former is imported before any other
>   imports (such as the default models import) and the latter is imported
>   after any other imports. Both have similar syntax. So in your
>   settings.py file:
>
> ```
> SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS = (
>     ('module.submodule1', ('class1', 'function2')),
>     ('module.submodule2', 'function3'),
>     ('module.submodule3', '*'),
>     'module.submodule4'
> )
> ```
>
> The above example would directly translate to the following python
>   code which would be executed before the automatic imports:
>
> ```
> from module.submodule1 import class1, function2
> from module.submodule2 import function3
> from module.submodule3 import *
> import module.submodule4
> ```
>
> These symbols will be available as soon as the shell starts.

Comment: I had to change `SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS` from a tuple to a list to get it working.

Comment: Don't forget the comma if you are importing one item: `SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS = ('haystack',)`

Comment: Where do you define SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS?  Settings.py?

Comment: @DanGoodrick yes

Comment: is there a mechanism to include some imports with aliases? A good use-case would be for the very-common aliases for data science related, like: `import numpy as np`, `import pandas as pd`, `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. EDIT: Sry, should have first looked in the docs: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/main/docs/shell_plus.rst#configuration

Answer (score 0):

ok, two ways:

1) using PYTHONSTARTUP variable (see this [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP))

```
#in some file. (here, I'll call it "~/path/to/foo.py"

def getproj(p_od):
    #I'm importing here because this script run in any python shell session
    from some_app.models import Project
    return Project.objects.get(project_id="asdf")

#in your .bashrc
export PYTHONSTARTUP="~/path/to/foo.py"
```

2) using ipython startup (my favourite) (See this [Docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/ipython.html#configuring-the-ipython-command-line-application),this [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1202) and this [Docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/overview.html#startup-files) ):

```
$ pip install ipython
$ ipython profile create
# put the foo.py script in  your profile_default/startup directory.
# django run ipython if it's installed. 

$ django-admin.py shell_plus
```

Comment: Both great - but I want to include this in source control, and as it happens this config is built in - see my answer below